# How do I build an NDK app with Android Studio 2.1 and com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I've Googled for a bit, but all the NDK examples seem to use com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0.

The examples from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk also use com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0.

If I switch to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0, these projects simply don't build. Firstly there is the error where it cannot find plug-in for `apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'` (had to change to `'com.android.application'`), and symbols inside `android.ndk { ... }`, such as `CFlags`, `cppFlags`, `ldLibs` cannot be resolved.

It looks like the entire ndk section was removed according to http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html.

Can someone please point me to the right direction on how to properly build an Hello World NDK app using com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 in Android Studio 2.1? There must be some tricks I am missing here.

Comment: Android Studio 2.1 does not have official support for NDK. Version 2.2 was presented at the recent I/O and is currently in public beta. Among other ausome features, it delivers 3 ways to integrate debuggable C++ code.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.